# copying the actual values of a 2d array to another 2d array c++

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, fstream, filereader

I'm new to c++ and ive Been trying to wrap my head around this all day. I am trying to read a data file that contains an unknown amount of rows (teacher said wont be more than 100 rows though). Each row contains 4 integers whose values range from 0-100. The 4 columns represent student test scores over the course of a semester. Each line/row represents one student's scores. while each column represents 1 test. I am to set up a 2D array to read the scores into. The scores from the data file go into the first 4 columns and the average of all 4 tests calculated in column 5 for each student/row. I will have rows 0 through n-1 due to the fact that i dont know how many students/rows are in the file. On the nth row i calculate each position row[0 through 4] as the average of the entire column above it. The average grade of all the students calculated at the bottom of each column row(nth) and each students average for all four tests calculated in column 5. The average each students test average calculated at the bottom of column 5 (grades[nth row][5] ={average of all rows in column 5}

Im sure a little broader knowledge base would be extremely beneficial, but this was a homework assignment so i had to try. I think pointers would have been the most beneficial thing to understand for this assignment; however, i just havent gotten there yet.

This was my first attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
double grades [100][5] = {0};
int row = 0;
int column = 0;

int main() {
char line[100];
ifstream myfile("sturec.dat");

if(myfile){
    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
        if (line == char) {
            //grades[row][column] = 
            cout << line << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i <= line.length(); i++) {
                if (line[i] != line[0]) && (i == " ") && (line[i+1] == char) {
                    column += 1;
                }
                else if (line[i] && line[i+1] && line[i+2] !== " ") {
                    grades[row][column] = {line[i] + line[i+1] + line[i+2]};
                else if (line[i] && line[i+1] !== " " ) {
                    grades [row][1] = {line[i] + line[i+1]};
                }


            }
            row += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

}
which i gave up on and started over with trying to create a vector of vectors to populate with the file. It took me a long time to figure out how to actually bring the data in from the file. Finally i resorted to:

```
#include //all the necessary libraries
using namespace std;
double grades[100][5] = {0}//the 2d array i had hoped to populate with the data from file

int main(){
ifstream myfile("filename");
rowCount = 0;
int t1, t2, t3, t4;
while(myfile >> t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4){
    cout << t1 << " " << t2 <<  " " << t3 << " " << t4 << endl;
            cout << "this is row 1 + : " << rowCount << endl;
//at this point i was just happy to have successfully read the file and printed the values.

            rowCount ++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    grades[rowCount][i]// this is where i got lost i tried multiple different things in attempt to populate "grades" by trying to create temp arrays to hold the values of t1,2,3,4 in order to parse them and place them in "grades", but to no avail. Any direction would be appreciated.
}
```

just to show some of my different approaches, i'll post the slightly different versions of similar code that i have.

``

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
double grades[100][5] = {0};

int main() {
    ifstream myfile("sturec.dat");
    int rowCount = 0;
    int tempArray[100][4] = {0};
    char test [4] = {0};
    int i = 0;      
        while (myfile >> tempArray[rowCount][i]) {
            cout << rowCount << endl << " " << i << endl;
            cout << "temp array: " << tempArray<< endl;
            while(i < 4){
                i++;
                rowCount++;
            }
        }
        /*for (int c = 0; c <= rowCount; c++) {
            for (int r = 0; r <= i; r++) {
                grades[rowCount][i] = (tempArray[r][c]);
            }
        }
    cout<< tempArray << endl << grades << endl; 
    */
}
    /*double final;
    while (myfile >> grades[rowCount][test]) {
        //cout << t1 << " " << t2 <<  " " << t3 << " " << t4 << endl;
        cout << grades << endl;
        cout << rowCount << endl;
                //cout << grades[rowCount][]
        rowCount ++;
    }


}
   */
```

next

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
double grades[100][5] = {0};

int main() {
ifstream myfile("sturec.dat");
int rowCount = 0;
int tempArray[100] = {0};
int t1, t2, t3, t4;
while (myfile >> t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4) {
    cout << t1 << " " << t2 <<  " " << t3 << " " << t4 << endl;
    int test [4] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; (i < sizeof(test) - 1); i++) {
            grades[rowCount][i] = {tempArray};
    }
}
double final;
while (myfile >> grades[rowCount][i]) {

    cout << grades << endl;
    cout << rowCount << endl;
            //cout << grades[rowCount][]
    rowCount ++;
}



vector < vector <int> > grades(100);
//vector <int> rows(4/*,0*/); // assigns 4 columns to rows vector with value of zero
//rows.assign(5,0);
int row = 0;

myfile.open("sturec.dat", ios::in); //opens file
if (myfile.is_open()) {

    cout << "file opened" << endl;

    string line;
    vector<string> myLines;
    while (getline(myfile, line)) { //gets lines using myfile and puts them in line
        myLines.push_back(line);

        cout << "string line contains: " << line << endl;
        for (int columns = 0; columns <= 4 /*sizeof(rows)*/; columns ++) {
            myfile >> grades[row][columns];         cout << "2" << endl;

        }
        row += 1;
    }
}

else cout << "cannot open file" << endl;
myfile.close(); cout << "closed file" << endl;
return 0;

//cout << grades;
```

}

last one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
ifstream myfile;
vector < vector <int> > grades(100);
//vector <int> rows(4/*,0*/); // assigns 4 columns to rows vector with value of zero
//rows.assign(5,0);
int row = 0;

myfile.open("sturec.dat", ios::in); //opens file
if (myfile.is_open()) {
    cout << "1" << endl;
    cout << "file opened" << endl;

    string line;
    vector<string> myLines;
    while (getline(myfile, line)) { //gets lines using myfile and puts them in line
        myLines.push_back(line);

        cout << "string line contains: " << line << endl;
        for (int columns = 0; columns <= 4 /*sizeof(rows)*/; columns ++) {
            myfile >> grades[row][columns];         cout << "2" << endl;

        }
        row += 1;
    }
}

else cout << "cannot open file" << endl;
myfile.close(); cout << "closed file" << endl;
return 0;

//cout << grades;
```

}
This one actually got me the first line of the file but i couldnt get this error to go away:
Run Command: line 1: 13531 Segmentation fault: 11  ./"$2" "${@:3}"

Comment: vector < vector <int> > grades(100,vector<int>(5,0));

Comment: C++ is not a language well suited to trial-and-error syntax

Comment: "// this is where i got lost " - it sounds like you just wanted `grades[rowcount][0] = t1; grades[rowcount][1] = t2; grades[rowcount][2] = t3; grades[rowcount][3] = t4;`, and also put that code inside the `while` loop instead of after it, and increment `rowcount`.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector < vector <int> > grades(100);
```

initializes a vector containing 100 `vector<int>`s of size 0. To avoid the segmentation fault in your last example, you should either initialize this as

```
vector < vector <int> > grades(100,vector<int>(5,0));
```

or replace `myfile >> grades[row][columns];` with something like

```
int tmp;
myfile >> tmp;
grades[row].push_back(tmp);
```